# PlaceAutocomplete search bar loses focus when clicked

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, placeautocompletefragment

I have an activity with two fragments: PlaceAutoComplete fragment search bar and google maps. Ideally, the search bar should stay focused when clicked and should allow searches, however as soon as it is clicked, the search bar loses focus and the map is displayed again.

The XML I am using for the activity is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The java class code is:

```
package com.kindred.kindred;

/**
 * Created by Fahad Saleem on 2/9/2018.
 */
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutoComplete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_fragment);

        placeAutoComplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
        placeAutoComplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

                Log.d("Maps", "Place selected: " + place.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.d("Maps", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: The solution is already presented in the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449649/android-google-places-api-getautocompletepredictions-returns-status-places-api