# Trying to get place from place picker but it open and closes

Tags: android, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I am integrating place picker but I have already enable places api but it opens and close immediately.

I have created api key and puted it on manifest file 
still it not working.in my logcat it gives me error

> 2019-03-08 10:31:41.640 2837-2358/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
>   2019-03-08 10:31:41.651 4713-4713/? E/Places: Place Picker closing due to PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED
>   2019-03-08 10:31:41.775 2837-2358/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
>   2019-03-08 10:31:41.776 2837-2358/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=SearchPlaces
>       OperationException[Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}]

**here is my code**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="key" />


 @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void showPlacePicker() {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(NewOrderActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, NewOrderActivity.this);
                edt_pickup_address.setText(place.getAddress());
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(place.getLatLng().latitude, place.getLatLng().longitude, 1);
                    if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                      /*  post_area = listAddresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                        post_city = listAddresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
                        post_state = listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();*/

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                String place_phone_number = "" + place.getPhoneNumber();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(place_phone_number)) {
                    String[] phone_number = place_phone_number.split(" ");
                    String s = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < phone_number.length; i++) {
                        if (i != 0) {
                            s = s + phone_number[i];
                        }
                    }
//                    et_contact_no_add_company.setText(s);
                } else {
//                    et_contact_no_add_company.setText("");
                }
                if (place.getWebsiteUri() != null) {
//                    et_website_add_company.setText("" + place.getWebsiteUri());
                } else {
//                    et_website_add_company.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Google Places API, getAutocompletePredictions returns status 'PLACES\_API\_ACCESS\_NOT\_CONFIGURED'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449649/android-google-places-api-getautocompletepredictions-returns-status-places-api)

Comment: but i have done it already still it clos

Answer (score 0):

As per Google new update the `Place Picker Deprecate` and it will not longer available in future, here is official statement

> **Deprecation notice: Place Picker**
>
> **Notice:** The Place Picker (Android, iOS) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019,
>   and will no longer be available after that date. To continue using the
>   Place Picker with Places SDK for iOS v.2.7.0 through the deprecation
>   period, do NOT disable the Places SDK for iOS. Read the migration
>   guides (Android, iOS) to learn more.

So, the other side u can use the  [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete)

But here is some limitation in new Place API you must enable the Billing account to use the Place Autocomplete.

> **Reminder:** To use the Places API, you must get an API key and you must
>   enable billing. You can enable billing when you get your API key (see
>   the Quick guide) or as a separate process (see Usage and Billing).

Alternative solution: get the `latLong` from place name using [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder)

Answer (score 0):

**Deprecation notice: Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android**

**[image: ndroid]**

Please refer this link

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete