# When i select select PlaceAutocompleteFragment that time this error shows

Tags: android

My code

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(ViewProperty.this);


        PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.getLatLng()).title(place.getName().toString()));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place.getLatLng()));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLng(), 12.0f));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.w("myApp", status.toString());
            }
        });
```

Error :

```
:InputMethodManager: startInputInner : InputBindResult == null need restart W/myApp: Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}
```

Comment: Please create a project on google cloud console and allow auto-complete API

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize google places first

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
      Places.initialize(context, "GOOGLE PLACES API KEY HERE")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Go to https://console.developers.google.com/
- enabling Places SDK for Android.
- refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31449953/8879491